# make certain pages expire after specific time and redirect to home page

Tags: php, .htaccess

For example i have this url

> mysite.com/page1-bla-bla.html

that have time specific content will be available for specific time period then after that the url should redirect to home page.

i think this will the solution for the problem i found today when i checked my google webmaster account today and found that i have many crawl errors due to 500 internal server error from pages that their content has expired as the content in this kind of pages is time limited available for specific time.

i have no idea how to do this may be htaccess is the solution or what?

looking for your ideas

Comment: i want to redirect the link to home page if it give this error http://www.telelivesports.com/Free-Live-Streaming-Video-Online-Other-Fighting-Fighting-WWE-Main-Event-164357.html check the link

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it's being done programmatically in your PHP script, this would let you have more control over the data and logic. But if you want to do something like this in your .htaccess, check out this article on time-related usage of mod_rewrite: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/time_hour-rewritecond-time.html.

Comment: not what i mean i want to redirect the url after when i give error only

Comment: Then you don't have choice but to catch an [exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) in your PHP script and create a [redirect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) from there. .htaccess would be of no help here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood the question, you could add the following to the `<head>` of the HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600;URL=http:/mysite.com/" />
```

This will redirect the browser to the address `http:/mysite.com/`after `600` seconds (10 mins).

Edit:

```
$hours = intval(date('H'));
if ($hours < 7) {
    header('Location: http:/mysite.com/');
    die();
}
```

Comment: not what i mean i want to redirect the url after when i give error only

Comment: See edit. You can obviously have whatever conditional expression you want in that if block.